# UPDATE Query and echo it in one refresh page?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I refresh my page, it queries but it wont update the echo untill the next refresh again... How do I make it so it queries and update echo in one refresh?

My current code is:

```
$curTime = time();
$endTime = $results->data[$i]['ends'];

if ($endTime < $curTime) 
{
    $query = "UPDATE sb_bans SET RemoveType='E' WHERE bid='1'";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $UnbannedReason = "(Expired)";
    echo $UnbannedReason;
}
```

EDIT: After Daniel's idea, it still does not echo new data after UPDATE even when SELECT'ing it:

```
$query = "SELECT RemoveType FROM sb_bans WHERE bid='1'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

if ($results->data[$i]['RemoveType'] == 'E')
{
    $UnbannedReason = "(Expired)";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update data and select new result again?

Comment: Did you not search for "how to refresh a page php" at all?

Comment: Yes show new result after the Query UPDATE when refreshing page.

Comment: Don't think you get it, Funk Forty Niner. I want to UPDATE Query + echo new results in one refresh.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you saying that you have pulled data from the database, then you do an update, and you then want for that original data to be updated? Then do what Daniel said, do the select again after the update.

Comment: I tried that, but nothing happens. Look what I edited in the post